# Add child view to two layouts (multiple parents)

Tags: android, view

I want to add the same view to a new RelativeLayout which is added earlier to another.

```
 RelativeLayout1
   -- View1
   -- ScrollView
      -- Linear Layout2
```

I have a view added to linear layout2 which is added to the scrollview. I want to add the same child view to the RelativeLayout1 in the place of View1.

I add the views this way,

```
MyCustomScrollView scrollView = new MyCustomScrollView(context);
  layout2 = new LinearLayout(context);

  for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
     layout2.addView(list.get(i));

  scrollView,add(layout2);
  relativeLayout1.addView(scrollView);
```

Now I want to add the same view from list to RelativeLayout1 in the place of View1

```
 RelativeLayout1.remove(view1);
 RelativeLayout1.addView(list.get(0),0);



Causes 

java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:2062)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1957)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1914)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `View` cannot be a child of two `ViewGroup` parents.

Feel free to clone the `View` and add the clone to the second parent.

Comment: @dcanh121: By "clone", I mean create another instance of the same class, and set it to have the same properties.